How can I configure a PowerShell session to gracefully and reliably end after a request to terminate from another process?
Consider the following background:

None of the obvious methods of programmatically stopping PowerShell from another process result in clean{} running.
Stop-Process "jumps straight to kill" without even trying the standardized but unreliable methods of requesting termination like WM_CLOSE and GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent as described here.
There are countless clues that ported programs that successfully use POSIX signals like SIGTERM on other platforms don't succeed at doing the same on Windows.  Perhaps this comment most succinctly summarizes what that situation appears to be.

Now consider a PowerShell session running some of my code.  I can press CTRL+C at the console, the clean{} blocks are executed, a cascade of Dispose() calls occurs through any active Cmdlet's and other object trees, and the process gracefully stops after all that cleanup is complete.  I would like to invoke a similar degree of orderly stopping from another process.
How can I achieve that in a manner that is reliable?

As discussed extensively in comments from your own answer, an approach that would work consistently for a PowerShell process (including Jobs) that would allow to invoke their clean block is via connecting to the process using a NamedPipeConnectionInfo and calling CloseAsync() on the process runspaces that are not the DefaultRunspace.
This seem to work consistently however it's important to note that if the process is invoking a .NET method that doesn't allow interrupts (i.e.: Thread.Sleep(-1)) then this fails.
using namespace System.Management.Automation

function Stop-PowerShell {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [System.Diagnostics.Process] $Process,

        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateRange(1, [int]::MaxValue)]
        [int] $TimeoutSeconds = 10)

    process {
        try {
            $pipe = [Runspaces.NamedPipeConnectionInfo]::new($Process.Id)
            $rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace($pipe)
            $rs.Open()
            $ps = [powershell]::Create($rs).AddScript({
                Get-Runspace |
                    Where-Object { $_ -ne [runspace]::DefaultRunspace } |
                    ForEach-Object CloseAsync
            })
            $null = $ps.InvokeAsync()
            if (-not $Process.WaitForExit([timespan]::FromSeconds($TimeoutSeconds))) {
                $PSCmdlet.WriteError([ErrorRecord]::new(
                    "Failed to stop PowerShell with Process Id '$($Process.Id)'.",
                    'StopFailed',
                    [ErrorCategory]::OperationTimeout,
                    $null))
            }
        }
        catch {
            $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
        }
        finally {
            ${ps}?.Dispose()
            ${rs}?.Dispose()
        }
    }
}

A variant of this approach could be via reflection, by GetCurrentlyRunningPipeline() and StopAsync():
$ps = [powershell]::Create($rs).AddScript({
    $method = [runspace].GetMethod(
        'GetCurrentlyRunningPipeline',
        [System.Reflection.BindingFlags] 'NonPublic, Instance')

    Get-Runspace |
        Where-Object { $_ -ne [runspace]::DefaultRunspace } |
        ForEach-Object {
            if ($pipeline = $method.Invoke($_, $null)) {
                $pipeline.StopAsync()
            }
        }
})


”… if the process is invoking a .NET method that doesn't allow interrupts (i.e.: Thread.Sleep(-1)) then this fails.” I expect this is a natural consequence of the .Net cancellation model which is, by design, cooperative.

@alx9r yep, at least using CloseAsync you can regain control of your shell and get the error. I think that's ideal in this case.

I tested this technique with jobs and pwsh with a variety of arguments.  It seems to be reliable.  I haven't yet achieved a working solution from Windows PowerShell because of this issue.

@alx9r added the answer, didnt consider you were using 5.1

Thank you.  I tested this technique across all the obvious combinations of Windows PowerShell and PowerShell 7 sources and targets.  It seems to be robust across across the whole matrix.  This all seems like a success to me.

that's great, good to hear @alx9r btw, since i see you may be using 5.1, then ${var}?.Dispose() translates to if ($var) { $var.Dispose() }. you should change that part too

Explanation
This technique causes the target instance of pwsh.exe to listen for a particular named event using EventWaitHandle.  When that event is raised, the handler raises CTRL_C_EVENT via GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent.  That seems to have the same effect as pressing CTRL+C at the console.  The advantage is that another process can get a handle to and raise that event with no prerequisites aside from interpolating the target's process ID into the event name pattern.
In principle this could be conditionally invoked prior to Stop-Process for a pwsh instance by testing TryOpenExisting() to see if the target has registered the handle and, if it has, raising the event and allowing some time for the target to gracefully shut down.  If the target process does not shut down after a timeout, then the usual Stop-Process can be invoked to force termination.
To use this technique, the part in the <registration> tags needs to be invoked in an instance of pwsh.exe for that instance to gracefully respond to the signal.  The part in the <signal> tags (with the correct process ID interpolated) can then be invoked to signal the instance to stop gracefully.
How is this different from a job?
A job can only be stopped if you have its handle.  There can be instances of pwsh running that you want to gracefully stop but you did not start and so do not have a job handle to them.  This technique works without a job handle.
Why not use a named pipe?
Opening a connection by way of NamedPipeConnectionInfo to the target pwsh process can also be be used to raise CTRL_C_EVENT. (see Stop-PowerShellProcess here for an example.)  However, doing that to a process that happens to be a job seems to cause the caller session to irrecoverably lock up with the error
"The background process reported an error with the following message: 
"The named pipe target process has ended."."

A repro of that lockup is here.
It seems that something about the local session goes wrong when a remote instance of pwsh to which it is connected through a named pipe has CTRL_C_EVENT raised.
(Note there is a method using named pipes and a separate exectuable that might overcome this.)
Demo Code
The code below does the following:

Creates a script named remote.ps1 and starts an independent instance of pwsh.exe running that script.  That "remote" PowerShell instance then does the following:

logs its progress to a file
registers an event named pwsh_$PID_CTRL_C_EVENT_78008808-fb42-4ce6-b8bb-cfe8135a0914 to raise CTRL_C_EVENT via GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent
sleeps


The original script continues after creating the "remote" PowerShell instance and does the following:

raises that pwsh_$PID_CTRL_C_EVENT_78008808-fb42-4ce6-b8bb-cfe8135a0914 event that the "remote" process subscribed to
waits for the "remote" process to end
outputs the log written by the "remote" process



Note that running the demo code outputs
begin
clean

indicating that the end{} block was interrupted by the signal and did not complete, but the clean{} block did complete.
{
    begin { 'begin' | Set-Content .\log.txt }
    end {
        # <registration>
        $remote_ctrl_c_event =
            [System.Threading.EventWaitHandle]::new(
                $false,
                'ManualReset',
                "pwsh_$PID`_CTRL_C_EVENT_78008808-fb42-4ce6-b8bb-cfe8135a0914")

        Add-Type @'
namespace n { public static class c {
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("KERNEL32.dll",ExactSpelling=true,SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern bool GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(int dwCtrlEvent,int dwProcessGroupId);
    public static void RegisterCtrlC(
        System.Threading.WaitHandle handle
    ) {
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
            handle,
            (s,to) => GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(0,0),
            null,-1,true);
    }
}}
'@
        [n.c]::RegisterCtrlC($remote_ctrl_c_event)
        # </registration>
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1000
        'end' | Add-Content .\log.txt
    }
    clean { 'clean' | Add-Content .\log.txt }
} |
    Set-Content .\remote.ps1

$remote_process = Start-Process -FilePath pwsh.exe -ArgumentList .\remote.ps1 -PassThru
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
# <signal>
$remote_ctrl_c_event =
    [System.Threading.EventWaitHandle]::new(
        $false,
        'ManualReset',
        "pwsh_$($remote_process.Id)_CTRL_C_EVENT_78008808-fb42-4ce6-b8bb-cfe8135a0914"
    )
$remote_ctrl_c_event.Set() | Out-Null
# </signal>
while (Get-Process -Id $remote_process.Id -ea si) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10
}
Get-Content .\log.txt


How is this better than using a job or a named pipe? Seems like you're just reinventing the wheel.

@SantiagoSquarzon "Seems like you're just reinventing the wheel." I might be.  This definitely differs from a job in that the process targeted for shutdown is independent of the process invoking the shutdown.  But I see now that a named pipe can be attached to such a process to do the same, but that approach I haven't gotten working.

@SantiagoSquarzon "How is this better than...a named pipe?" Sadly the named pipe method doesn't seem to be viable. I've updated the answer with an explanation.

And why would you want to send a CTRL+C to a job when Stop-Job already allows the job to run its clean block? And btw, your current "solution" also does the same to a job, the clean block fails to run.

"And why would you want to send a CTRL+C to a job when Stop-Job already allows the job to run its clean block?" I don't think you would, but I'm not sure how that possibility could be reliably averted.

"And btw, your current "solution" also does the same to a job, the clean block fails to run." Indeed, the job is unaffected and just continues running.  I think that's arguably the preferable behavior since they're a job and, ostensibly, should be stopped by whichever of the PowerShell instances is the parent.  For that matter, I don't see a reason to register such an event in a job in the first place.

I still don't see how this is solution is better than a named pipe. Again, this approach fails to stop a normal Job. And "However, doing that to a process that happens to be a job seems to cause the caller session to irrecoverably lock up." is false. Anyways, not gonna keep beating around the bush, as long as you're happy with this ‍♂️

@SantiagoSquarzon Why not post a better solution?  I think you know more about these parts of PowerShell than I do.  I've tried to explain my reasoning in the answer, but I'm sure there are some things I've overlooked.

I already did here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79245560/15339544

@SantiagoSquarzon Yep.  I used that answer as inspiration, I didn't even know that was possible until you posted it.  But it's rather a different situation.  In that answer the first runspace opened with Start-Process is just an idle console rather than executing powershell whose execution of clean{} blocks is in question.

All your examples in all questions are showing powershell code, never show or give an example of a console application. In your real challenge are you developing a .NET console application were you set up the CTRL+C handler ? In that case jborean's kill.exe works perfectly well.

"In your real challenge are you developing a .NET console application were you set up the CTRL+C handler?"  The real challenge I'm facing here is just long-running PowerShell scripts.  Usually they just sit indefinitely waiting on file change or system events like USB resets and respond to them to do some utilitarian thing.  Some are windows services, others are VS Code tasks, some are running ad hoc.  They all need to be stopped from time to time.  Ideally that stopping could be done gracefully and reliably.

Ok so, since they're all powershell, NamedPipe always work even for a Job, you could invoke this: Get-Runspace | Sort-Object { $_ -eq [runspace]::DefaultRunspace } | ForEach-Object Dispose and it will allow the host to invoke its clean block (including a normal job) - of course this doesnt work if you're invoking a .NET method that doesn't allow the pipeline to stop (like Thread.Sleep however the same applies to your current implementation)

@SantiagoSquarzon Interesting.  Thank you for that option.  It looks like disposing any runspace in a job pwsh from a pipe-connected runspace causes that hang. But calling .Close() instead works!  So, I think that's a good option.

Mmm .Dispose works fine for me, I'm using this: https://gist.github.com/santisq/f28fa0e8e61c14c15197804dadf5a930 and it's consistently stopping processes and jobs and letting them invoke their clean. However if you put something like Thread.Sleep(-1) it will of course block forever since it doesnt allow interrupts.

I concur.  That incarnation of Stop-PowerShell seems to be working.  That should really be its own answer.  I think it's probably a better choice than this one.
